# Where can I ask questions on DMX-controlled stage light

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm looking for a program or hardware controller to do specific aiming of moving lights that are DMX-controllable.

The Electronics Stack Exchange don't seem to fit, the question is several layers of abstraction above.

Comment: Maybe video.se: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/22013/is-it-possible-to-build-a-dmx-usb-interface-that-is-compatible-with-resolume